# Facebook Android APP launch other APP wouldn't work (native deep link)

Tags: android, facebook, deep-linking

I have apply a facebook APP on facebook website, and also setup anything about "Native Android APP", include [package name][class name][Key Hash][Facebook login][Deep link] ware setup well.

The [package name] and [class name] was get from my manifest.

```
  <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name="com.mypackage.myapp.login.Login" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:launchMode="singleTask">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

And key hash was got from following code in my APP

```
PackageInfo info=getActivity().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.mypackage.myapp", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
for(Signature signature : info.signatures)
{
  MessageDigest md=MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
  md.update(signature.toByteArray());
  Log.d(Constants.TAG, "APP KeyHash: "+Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
}
```

So I'm pretty sure [package name] and [class name] and [Key Hash] ware all right.
And of course, I did turned [Facebook login] and [Deep link] on, in my facebook APP setup page.

At first, my Android APP was using facebook SDK 1.5, the deep linking function was working well.
I can click my app posted link on "Facebook Android APP", to launch "my Android APP".

But since facebook claimed that they'll stop supporting old 2.0 and below SDK, I upgraded facebook SDK to 3.0 in my app, and the deep linking just not working.

Now I click my app posted link on facebook, facebook android APP just ask me to select 1 of few browser, not launch my android APP anymore.

What should I do to let facebook deep linking working again, and even bring a parameter to my android app when it been launched ?

I really really need your help to overcome this issue, thanks all~

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: Solved by make sure anything posted onto facebook personal wall, ware post via my facebook app, not just a pure http link. So that the facebok android APP will open my android APP after I clicked that link.

Comment: "ware post via my facebook app, not just a pure http link" could you explain this, I'm suing FB SDK 4.1.2 and I have set everything as you did but deep linking is not working, knowing that I'm not posting to personal wall via FB Graph API, I use ShareDialog and ShareLinkContent.

Comment: Knowing that what I'm sharing via ShareDialog and ShareLinkContent is links to FB pages in format of (www.facebook.com/page_name).